# How to implement HTTP request queue in Java

Tags: java, architecture, queue, servlet-filters, java-ee-7

we are trying to setup Architecture for Application.This is first time for us.This Application is not interact with End-Users,it's for my internal computations purpose.
We have a remote `DBServer`(Ms sql server azure) with 1 database name as `DBTesting`. Whenever any data was modified in `DBTesting`,it triggers java Application name as `App1` .

Question 1:

What are the possibilities to trigger `App1` .

In `App1`, I am running `.exe` file,which is written in `C` language.It takes 20 min for evaluation. If `DBTesting` is modified many times with in 20 min, it sends that many number of requests from `DBTesting` to `App1`.But I don't want to handle more number of requests at a time.So I want to trigger `App1` in queue  base. Once previous `Http` request is done then only Queue will be release next HTTP request.

Question 2:

Is there any way to Implement this using `Java` or any other technologies

we are interacting Database with this [Link](https://coxy7ezff6.database.windows.net/)

UserName : MyUserName

Password : MyPassword

we are trying to fix these from 1 week,but we are not figure it out which way is good way.

can anyone suggest me with some tutorials, which are suitable to my requiments.

Thanks.

Comment: @All Is it possible using `Thread` concept.

Comment: In above question, if you give details of database(atleast server name) and some thing more related to application, it might be easier to answer. Diagram will help a lot.

Comment: @LearnMore I updated my question.can you check it once.

Comment: I updated my answer. If it is possible for you to create a queue using MS-SQL service broker and read that queue via from an external  application, I think it will work for you.

Comment: We chatted and clarified. Were you able to get it done ??

Comment: While chat time, I said messages are sent from `DB` to Java Application(Which App is running .EXE file). Db part was done by one of colleague. So just for my testing I wrote one more Java class for sending text messages to `Activemq` name as `MessageSender.java`.It's working fine.I tried to write another java class for receiving messages from `Activemq`.But I am getting all the messages at a time.Still I didn't figure it out.For this I post the following link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128089/how-can-i-push-messages-from-activemq-to-java-application`.check it.

Comment: added answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Active-MQ for queuing. [Active MQ, Hello World](http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html)

If you are using [MSSQL service broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), it already provides [Message Queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue). you just need to figure out how to use it properly in your case.

This is link to [Service Broker to JMS bridge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sb2jmsbridge/).

- You do not need to invoke any application via Database.
- C program is taking 20 minutes to process each HttpRequest.

Use following steps:

Part 1:

- p1.1 - Setup a queue using [MSSQL service broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).
- p1.2 - Each time database changes, send a message to queue.

Part 2:

- p2.1 - Have a Java program which polls queue and checks if there are any messages.
- p2.2 - If there are no messages, it sleeps for some time.
- p2.3 - If there are new messages, it just takes one.
- p2.4 - The message, is passed to C program by Java program(see [Process Builder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) ) .
- p2.5 - Wait for the process to complete.
- p2.6 - When process completes(after 20 minutes ), go to p2.1.

[This link might help you indirectly.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn246927.aspx)

Since Azure does not support service broker, there has to be other way to implement part1.

---

Part1 (Implement below steps in way possible ):

- Step 1. Generate request-data(not message, just data) when database changes.

  `I want to send modified or new data with request from DB to Java Application`

  - I need to know how/where data is generated/gathered when database changes. Only this much in this step. Once this is clear, then we will forward. Please take one step at a time. -
- Step 2. Create messages from data generated.
- Step 3. Read messages and send them to queue.

  `send messages including data to Queue`

  message Structures:

  The following message points to `Application1`.

  ```
   App1?data="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10..."
  ```

  The following message points to `Application2`.

  ```
   App2?data="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10..."
  ```

  `If it allow to mention our own custom message,then I will create one more table in    DB.This table have 2 columns.1 row points to ApplicationName and 2 row points to message Name.It is useful while forwarding time.`

Part 2(As of now remains same):

- p2.1 - Have a Java program which polls queue and checks if there are any messages.
- p2.2 - If there are no messages, it sleeps for some time.
- p2.3 - If there are new messages, it just takes one.
- p2.4 - Java Application imports XMl file and based on message context it will send http request to that corresponding Application including data
- p2.5 - The message, is passed to C program by Java program(see [Process Builder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) ) .
- p2.6 - Wait for the process to complete.
- p2.7 - When process completes(after 20 minutes ), go to p2.1.

Xml Structure is in the following way.

```
   <Message>
     <Message-Body>
       <Message-Context>App1</Message-Context>
       <URL>`http://localhost:8080/App1`</URL>
     </Message-Body>
     <Message-Body>
        <Message-Context>App2</Message-Context>
        <URL>`http://localhost:8080/App2`</URL>
     </Message-Body>
   </Message>
```

Comment: you mean `JMS` queue send request to `App2` or `App2` will read from JMS Queue. I never work on `JMS`.

Comment: JMS queue will only act as a channel of communication between DB and APP2. You can write code in both applications to send and receive to/from queue. If you have not worked on it, do not worry. It is as easy as creating an object and passing it to a function, with some concepts from Serialization :) .

Comment: If you don't mine can you suggest me with any tutorials.

Comment: Start with Serialization in JAVA. Then check Apache Active MQ tutorial. If you have problem, just post here.

Comment: BTW, how do you check if DB is modified and how the request reaches APP2 as of now ?

Comment: using Service broker concept I can send `Http` requests from `DB` to any Application.That means Instead of browser I am triggering Applications by `DB`.

Comment: I am sorry asking this question, Am I need to write any `Java` code for creating `JMS` Queue,sending messages to Queue....
don't mine, I am new to Java Technology.

Comment: Yes you need to. Your flow is not clear. Please update information in question. Comments are not suitable for this.

Comment: @All I updated my question with clear details,can you check it once.

Comment: I installed `Activemq` and open Activemq console page in browser.After that I am not sure what will I do.I didn't understand flow of `JMS` working from your links.

Comment: I can guide step by step. But I am not sure if you need AMQ. What you need is to Create a Queue via MS-SQL Service Broker and poll the queue via Java program.

Comment: Initially I thought to create Queue via MS-SQL Service Broker,but `MS-Sql Server Azure` not supported `Service Broker`.So I think to divide my work into 2 parts. 1 part corresponds to sending messages to `Activemq` in any way from `MS-SQL Server Azure`. 2 Part corresponds to pushing messages to Java App name as `App1`,here it decide These message corresponds to which Application. may be you get doubt how `App1` decide.For this I use XML file. I think If I do like this later If I want to add Apps just I need to change XML code. `@Learn More` what did you say on my idea is it efficient way.

Comment: First challenge is to successfully share messages between application. Once that is achieved, then we will worry about any other thing. How you are going to implement part 1 ?

Comment: Really I don't have any idea,I think 2 part is easy to implement so I think to start that.For this I create messages manually in `Activemq` console.Really `@Learn More` my mind is not working because of this challenge.

Comment: I am starting to put steps in my answer. I will put comment. You edit and add a response. It is not easy to follow in comments.

Comment: `@Learn More` Am I need to edit your answer or my question according to your answer.

Comment: Please add at places where I wrote comment here. Use your own fonts. Do not edit what I have written.

Comment: I modified.Sorry I added one more `p2.4` in part2 for your better understanding, what I am thinking.

Comment: @user2642355 Please take one step at a time.  As of now part1>step1. Is that clear ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35010/discussion-between-user2642355-and-learn-more)

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be have a table in your DB with the Http Requests and a program running queries, when finds a result make the request if not sleep.

while(true){

```
//query the DB
if (have_results){
         //http request
         // remove request from the DB

 }else{
     // sleep 1s

}
```

}

it isn't code but It should be easy.

Thanks

Comment: I want to pass parameters with `Http` request.That parameters will be change dynamically. If you change configuration in `Application server`,It can also allow only 1 request at a time. Compared to `DB Table` it is very easy.But why I am doing this using `Java`,If I want to change anything later,I can easily modify my code.It's like maintainability issue. So I want to implement in Java.I hope you understand What i am trying here.

Comment: As far your suggestion, If I make a table in my `DB`. How can I know wheather previous request is it completed or not ?

Comment: If you make a table for the request, and another for the parameters for each request, you don't need to change it each time.

Comment: If are queering the database all the time, when the program get a request just execute and delete the request.